# vector bundle stacks

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Does anybody know a good reference where to study vector bundle stacks?
I am interested in a situation of this type:
$f:\mathcal{F}\to\mathcal{G}$ is a morphism of stacks which is non-representable but whose fibers have constant dimension. Is this a vector bundle stack?

Comment: I really think you should give more information in your question.  Based off of what you have said, I would likely think that your map is flat and not necessarily anything more.  Have you checked that $f$ is smooth?  Secondly, what exactly do you mean by vector bundle stack?  Do your fibers look something like the quotient stack $V/W$ for some finite dimensional vector spaces $V$ and $W$ (for example, the tangent stack is something like this)?

Answer (score 3):

The conditions that you list are certainly not enough for something to be a vector bundle stack.

Forget stacks.
Even for varieties, the conditions that you list are not enough to be a vector bundle: you're just asking that the fibers have constant dimension...

So, to your question *"Is this a vector bundle stack?"*, I respond, perhaps disappointingly, *"no"*.

Comment: You might want to rephrase your question, and ask something like "what is a vector bundle stack?".